# What did I do wrong with subset()

Tags: r

I was trying to limit my scatter plot to "midterm" = 0. But R keeps giving me error.

Error in `ggplot()`:
! `mapping` should be created with `aes()`.
✖ You've supplied a <data.frame> object

What did I do wrong?

```
mcdon %>% 
  ggplot(subset(mcdon, midterm %in% 0)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = year, y = turnout_rate)) +
  labs(
    title = "Turnout rate over time for resident election",
    x = "Year", y = "Turnout rate"
  )
```

Midterm equals 0 or 1 in my dataset. The data frame is called mcdon. I'm trying to graph a scatter plot with "year" in the x axis and "turnout_rate" in the y axis, but I only want to graph the data that has midterm = 0.

Comment: The pipe operator passes the object on its left as the first argument of the function to its right. So you are passing two data frames to ggplot. That’s not right…

Comment: Perhaps try `mcdon %>% subset(midterm %in% 0) %>% ggplot() + .......`

Comment: Why not use a filter step?